# Uniform Istio service address for internal and external use

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a need to propagate a header to a service that contains a callback address.  How can I get a host/port combination that will work both inside the Istio service mesh as well outside the service mesh, i.e., and external service.  For example, I have a service S1 in namespace N that calls some other service S2 that may or may not be in the service mesh.  I want to pass to S2 some address it can use to callback to S1.  What address do I use?

-tl

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is using Oracle Container Infrastructure (OKE).  Client version v1.22.2, server version v1.21.5

Comment: Please add your yaml files to reproduce your problem